# Next.js, VPS server and .gltf files

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-three-fiber, gltf, react-three-drei

I made a project using **three.js + reaction/three fiber**. Everything works on **localhost**, even if I did the **build** and download via **npm run start**, but when I did the same on my vps server, he wrote this:

```
http://IP:3000/models/model.gltf 404 (Not found)
```

Although he finds other static (pictures, etc.). I've been working on the problem for more than a day. I really need your help (models in gltf format)

I tried to change the next config, tried to locate the folder on the server in different ways, tried to change the paths in the project, but nothing helps

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try registering a MIME Type for `*.gltf` as `model/gltf+json` on the server.  `*.glb` can also be registered as `model/gltf-binary`.